# Abstract takes its own column, pushes first section to second column

Tags: two-column, abstract

I am using the [`acm_proc_article-sp`](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/acm_proc_article-sp.cls/view)  class to prepare a conference paper. It should not exceed the length of 4 pages. Unfortunately, the abstract will push the first chapter to the second column, even if there's enough space for a few paragraphs to fit in the first. This essentially pushes my references to the fifth page.

You can see the output here:

[image]

All I'm using is:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\title{Title Title Yada Yada}
\numberofauthors{1}
\author{
\and
\alignauthor
Author \\
       \affaddr{Institute}\\
       \affaddr{University}
}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\category{H.1.2}{User/Machine Systems}{Human Factors}
\section{Introduction}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{document}
```

Question: **How can I force the Introduction to begin in the left column?**

If there are any changes to be made in the `acm_proc_article-sp` class, please suggest them, as I'm a beginner in TeX and therefore have no idea how to change the classes' behavior. It's okay if I modify the class file, the conference isn't too strict when it comes to that.

It seems to work though if the text in the introduction has fewer paragraph breaks. So maybe the problem is just telling LaTeX to break up the introduction if necessary.

**Update:** Using the [`sig-alternate.cls`](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.cls) produces similar problems:
[image]

Comment: You're going to need to provide a minimal example that exhibits the problem. It works fine for me. I used `\lipsum[1]` for the abstract and `\lipsum` for the introduction. If you're able, you might want to try the (misnamed) sig alternate class.

Comment: @TH I updated my question - now with an example an source that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @slhck: That example is not complete. I cannot compile it as is.

Comment: As this is a custom class, I'd be tempted to check with the people who provide it. This may be a known issue or something deliberate  (if odd!).

Comment: @TH Well of course it isn't a complete document, it's just the parts between `\begin{abstract}` and `\end{document}`. I'll edit it anyway.

Comment: @slhck: are you getting the unexpected behaviour with the *exact* code you posted? I ask you because I compiled it and didn't get any strange results.

Comment: @Gonzalo Yes, definitely. I double checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the funny part:

I'm using *pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.11-2.2 (TeX Live 2010)* with *TextMate 1.5.10*, which has two methods of compiling the file:

1. Using the "LaTeX - Typeset and View" command
2. Using the "Watch Document" command

When I use "Watch Document", this is what I get:

[image]

When I use "LaTeX - Typeset and View", look what happens:

[image]

Problem solved. Anybody got an idea why that is?